# How do I rewind a for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop

How do you rewind or go back to the start of a for loop?

I tried to use "x=0" in an else statement like this:

```
            outerloop:
            for(int x=0; x<arr.length; x++){
                if(counter == countnum){
                    if(arr[x]!=0){
                        temp1 = Integer.toString(arr[x]);
                        death = death + " " + temp1;
                        arr[x] = 0;
                        counter=1;
                    }
                }

                else{
                    counter++;
                }

                if(x==(arr.length-1)){
                    for(int y=0; y<arr.length; y++){
                        if(arr[y]!=0){
                            x=0;
                        }
                        else
                            break outerloop;
                    }
                }
            }
```

It doesn't work. I found out about the iterator, but I don't think it'd work, rather, I don't understand how it works.

Here's an update since nobody seems to understand my situation:

This is what I wanted to happen:

For the input:  1 2 3 4

an input sequence is 2, then output should be rearranged: 2 4 3 1
accordingly to the input sequence. So I tried to return the for loop count back to 0, but it only shows: 2 4.  it doesn't return to x=0 where arr[x(which is =0)]. That's my problem.

If you want, here's my entire source code:

```
import java.util.Random;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Josephus extends JFrame {

    JLabel title;
    JLabel men;
    JLabel count;
    JTextField mentext;
    JTextField countext;
    JTextArea display;
    JButton execute;
    JButton close;
    String menstring;
    String countstring;
    int menum;
    int countnum;
    Random rand = new Random();
    String generation = "Generated Men: ";
    String death = "Death Series:  ";
    int counter = 1;

    public Josephus(){

        super("");

        setLayout(null);

        title = new JLabel("Death Execution");
        title.setFont(new Font("Calibre", Font.BOLD, 20));
        title.setBounds(350, 15, 400, 25);
        add(title);

        men = new JLabel("Number of Men");
        men.setBounds(10, 60, 400, 25);
        add(men);

        mentext = new JTextField();
        mentext.setBounds(120, 60, 150, 25);
        add(mentext);

        count = new JLabel("Count of Death");
        count.setBounds(10, 100, 400, 25);
        add(count);

        countext = new JTextField(10);
        countext.setBounds(120, 100, 150, 25);
        add(countext);

        display = new JTextArea(5, 20);
        display.setEditable(false);
        display.setBounds(290, 60, 280, 200);
        add(display);

        execute = new JButton("Execute");
        execute.setBounds(105, 230, 80, 30);
        add(execute);

        execute.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                String temp;
                String temp1;
                menstring = mentext.getText();
                countstring = countext.getText();
                menum = Integer.parseInt(menstring);
                countnum = Integer.parseInt(countstring);

                int arr[] = new int[menum];

                for(int x=0; x<arr.length; x++){
                    if(x!=0){
                        if(arr[x]!=arr[x-1])
                            arr[x] = rand.nextInt(500)+1;
                        else
                            x--;
                    }
                    else
                        arr[x] = rand.nextInt(500)+1;
                }

                for(int x=0; x<arr.length; x++){
                    temp = Integer.toString(arr[x]);
                    generation = generation + " " + temp;
                }

                outerloop:
                for(int x=0; x<arr.length; x++){
                    if(counter == countnum){
                        if(arr[x]!=0){
                            temp1 = Integer.toString(arr[x]);
                            death = death + " " + temp1;
                            arr[x] = 0;
                            counter=1;
                        }
                    }

                    else{
                        counter++;
                    }

                    if(x==(arr.length-1)){
                        for(int y=0; y<arr.length; y++){
                            if(arr[y]!=0){
                                x=0;
                            }
                            else
                                break outerloop;
                        }
                    }
                }

                display.setText(generation + "\n" + death);
            }
        });

        close = new JButton("Close");
        close.setBounds(200, 230, 70, 30);
        add(close);

        close.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Josephus frame = new Josephus();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(600, 330);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
```

[image: Here's something...]

This is a JOSEPHUS EXECUTION program...

Edit:

I found a solution.

Comment: For every loop write its *invariant*. Ie what the variables mean just before the test every time. Ie  `x`, `counter` & `arr`. An *assertion* before the loop tells us what the constants mean. Eg `countnum`.After a loop we need to know what the values mean. This is said by another assertion. The goal of the loop was to repeatedly change values while advancing to  this goal. When the test is false, the invariant should be imply the after-assertion. Please try to give us these three statements so that a simpler and sounder loop can be written with fewer complicated ifs & tests and jumps.

Comment: Please be clearer in your explanation of what you wanted, it is unintelligible. Also: Stack Overflow questons about code not working need to have a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: welp..... dayummm... I have no idea...

Comment: i dunno... x is basically from the for loop, counter is like, the counter for the sequence for rearranging the numbers, then arr is the array... :3

Comment: Please consider posting your solution as an answer. It helps others. You can even accept it.

Answer (score 4):

The `for` loop

```
for(int x=0; x<arr.length; x++)
```

initializes `x=0` at the beginning. (Its first expression.) Before each execution of the body of the loop it tests `x<arr.length`. (Its second expression.) After the body of the loop but before the next test it executes `x++`. (The third expression.)

So the `x++` of the `for(int x=0; x<arr.length; x++)` happens after all the code in the loop. Then the test is re-done. You want `x` to be `0` when you get back to the test at the top of the loop. But in the `if` when `arr[y]!=0` you are setting `x` to `0` and then the `x++` in the for loop makes it `1` *before* the test is redone.

So you need to set `x=-1`. Then the `x++` in the for loop makes it `0` before the test is redone. Then the test is re-done with `x` `0`.

PS (After googling what you are not explaining.) (Although your code seems want to execute down to no survivors so I'll assume that.)

The top `if` "executes" the `x`th element of `arr` by setting it to zero if it is the `countnum`th nonzero `arr` element after the last one modulo `arr.length`. If the bottom `if` wrapped `x` back to `-1` from `arr.length-1` (per above) then a third statement could `break` the main loop when `arr` is all zero. Or if the bottom `if` wrapped `x` back to the first non-zero element of `arr` via `x=y-1` inside the `for(int y=0; y<arr.length; y++)` then afterwards you could break from the main loop when `x==arr.length-1`. But unfortunately your current code exits the main loop from the loop that looks for the next non-zero element as soon as a zero element is found.

Comment: or simply use a while loop with a custom condition instead of a for loop

Comment: @NikosM. This code is so ugly that that seemed moot.

Answer (score 1):

It's best not to get hacky when restarting loops.

```
int totalTimesRun = 0;

MAIN_LOOP:
while(true){
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            System.out.println(i + ", " + j);
            if(j == i && i == 1 && ++totalTimesRun < 3) {
                System.out.println("Restarting Loop");
                continue MAIN_LOOP;
            }
        }
    }


    break; //will always break out of MAIN_LOOP
           //unless continue MAIN_LOOP is called
}
```

Output

```
0, 0
0, 1
0, 2
1, 0
1, 1
Restarting Loop
0, 0
0, 1
0, 2
1, 0
1, 1
Restarting Loop
0, 0
0, 1
0, 2
1, 0
1, 1
1, 2  //since totalTimesRun is now 3 it runs
2, 0
2, 1
2, 2
```

The trick here is

```
while(true){
    //will only run once since break is at the end
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewinding the loop by changing the value of the counter (x in your case) should work.

I suspect the problem in is your inner loop :

```
            if(x==(arr.length-1)){
                for(int y=0; y<arr.length; y++){
                    if(arr[y]!=0){
                        x=0;
                    }
                    else
                        break outerloop;
                }
            }
```

You only rewind `x` if `arr[0]!=0`. Otherwise you break from the loop. Even if you do rewind `x`, you may still break from the loop if `arr[y]==0` for some y.

You can replace that code with :

```
        if(x==(arr.length-1)){
            for(int y=0; y<arr.length; y++){
                if(arr[y]!=0){
                    x=-1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

You don't need `break outerloop`, since the loop will end anyway if you don't reset `x` back to 0.

Comment: the problem with this solution is that, my whole program would loop infinitely or it works just the same with my previous code... would you like to see my whole source code?

Comment: @Lil'Dunno Well, if your code always resets `x`, you'll get an infinite loop. You should decide when you wish to re-run the loop and when you wish to end it. There must be some stopping condition.

Comment: Yes, that is the purpose of break outerloop... 

actually, This is what I wanted to happen:
for example;
input:  1 2 3 4
then, an input sequence is 2, then output should be rearranged: 2 4 3 1
accordingly to the input sequence. So I tried to return the for loop count back to 0, but it only shows: 2 4.  it doesn't return to x=0 where arr[x(which is =0)]. That's my problem.

Comment: @Lil'Dunno Well philipxy has a good point in his answer. You should reset x to -1, since the for loop will increase it to 0 before that next iteration. If you reset it to 0, in the next iteration it will be 1.

Answer (score 0):

Here somthing wrong if `arr[x]` is an int ypou cant do this `Integer.toString(arr[x])`, if no you  can't do this `arr[x]!=0`:

```
   if(arr[x]!=0){
    temp1 = Integer.toString(arr[x]);
```

Or maybe you mean:

```
     if(arr[x]!=0){
      temp1 = x;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rewinding a for loop, just set the values yourself.

```
int[] copy = arr;
copy[0]=arr[1];
copy[1]=arr[3];
copy[3]=arr[1];
arr=copy;
```

Sure it's a hack job, but because the purpose of a loop is to simplify things (which is not happening in your case), the easiest thing to do is not use a loop.